# How can I prevent the default loading of ftplugin/text.vim for certain *.txt files?

Tags: vimrc, filetype, startup

I have to edit a bunch of *.txt files for which I want to define a specific filetype. So, in my `vimrc`, I add a

```
autocmd! BufReadPost bunchOfFiles/*.txt :set ft=bunchOfFilesFT
```

This reads `ftplugin/bunchOfFilesFT.vim` as wanted. The problem is that it also reads `ftplugin/text.vim` since there is an according autocmd that was defined in `filetype.vim` that comes with a Vim installation.

Since my *bunchOfFilesFT* filetype should be completely independent of the *text* filetype (despite its suffix), I'd rather have Vim not load `ftplugin/text.vim`. Is this somehow possible?

Comment: Does your `ftplugin/text.vim` have a `if exists("b:did_ftplugin")` section at the beginning to `finish` early if some ftplugin has already been `did`? And do you set `b:did_ftplugin` in your `ftplugin/bunchofFilesFT.vim`?

Comment: No, I didn't. I guess this is the canonical way to proceed for what I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a good idea to begin plugins, colorschemes, etc., by checking that it has not already been run for the current buffer. This prevents running the plugin again if it's not necessary and it gives the user the ability to easily disable it. For an ftplugin this usually looks like

```
if exists("b:did_ftplugin")
  finish
endif
let b:did_ftplugin = 1
```

If your `text.vim` ftplugin does this, you can prevent it loading by setting the `b:did_ftplugin` variable before `text.vim` is loaded.

For example, Vim's `ftplugin/vim.vim` does a check like that. So I put the above snippet in `ftplugin/jjvim.vim` and

```
autocmd! BufReadPost *.vim :set ft=jjvim
```

in my vimrc. Then I start a new vim session and edit `ftplugin/jjvim.vim` again, and now only that ftplugin is loaded, not Vims `vim.vim`.

So make sure that your `text.vim` contains a check like above, and make sure you set `b:did_ftplugin` before `text.vim` is loaded, for instance from your `bunchofFilesFT.vim`, and you should be fine.